# source code visible on browser when i navigate language django and extension of page is html

Tags: html, django

[image]

please solve my error i am very sad of this stuff. I dont know the html is visible other url are working fine but the problem occurs only when i visit this above url

```css
body {
    color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, midnightblue, midnightblue 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 10%);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 100%;
    transition: background-position 275ms ease;
}
.form-control {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #ddd;
    
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #000000; 
}
.login-form {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.login-form form {
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: rgb(170, 255, 0);
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    
    padding: 30px;
}
.login-form h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.login-form .avatar {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #4aba70;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.login-form .avatar i {
    font-size: 62px;
}
.login-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.login-form .form-control, .login-form .btn {
    min-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.login-form .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
.login-form .btn {
    background: #000000;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    line-height: normal;
}
.login-form .btn:hover, .login-form .btn:focus {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border: 10px 2px 4px #000000;
}
.login-form .checkbox-inline {
    float: left;
}
.login-form input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.login-form .forgot-link {
    float: right;
}
.login-form .small {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.login-form a {
    color: #4aba70;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Campus-Portal-Fees</title>


    <!-- Additional CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'%} >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'assets/css/font-awesome.css'%} >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'assets/css/index.css'%}>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "assets/css/owl-carousel.css"%}>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    


<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/order.css' %}>

</head>

<body>



    <header class="header-area header-sticky  ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="main-nav navbar-dark " style='position:fixed-top'>
                        <!-- ***** Logo Start ***** -->
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                            Pay - Fees
                        </a>
                        <!-- ***** Logo End ***** -->
                        <!-- ***** Menu Start ***** -->
                        <ul class="nav">
                                                    
                          
                          {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                            <li class="scroll-to-section">  <p class="mr-sm-2 my-2 mx-6 text-dark">Hello <span style="text-transform:uppercase;"> <b style='color:salmon'>{{ user.username  }}</b> </span> </p></li>
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 mx-6 my-sm-0" type="" href="{% url 'logout' %}"> Logout</a>
                          
                          {% endif %}
                          
             

                        </ul>
                        <a class='menu-trigger'>
                            <span>Menu</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- ***** Menu End ***** -->
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>





    <div class="login-form" style='margin-top:100px'>


        <a type="" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg text-warning" href="../payments/"><- Back to Dashboard </a>            


      <form action="{% url 'payment_status' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

<center>

      <h4>Your Details</h4>


          <div class="gender" style="margin-bottom:20px">
              Fees  {{ price }}  
          </div>

     </center>     
            
            
         
            <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ name }}" disabled></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ phone }}" disabled></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ email }}" disabled></div>


       <script    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
                   data-key="rzp_test_3rwBYBLYRPHJWd"
                   data-amount="{{ price }}"
                   data-currency="INR"
                   data-order_id="{{ order_id }}"
                   data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
                   data-name="Campus Portal"
                   data-description="Education Fees "
                   data-image="{% static 'images/apple-touch-icon.png' %}"
                   data-prefill.name="{{ name }}"
                   data-prefill.email="{{ email }}"
                   data-prefill.contact="{{ phone }}"
                   data-theme.color="#F37254">
                   
                   
                   
        </script>
        <input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">



      </form>

  </div>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src={% static "assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" %}></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src={% static "assets/js/popper.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}></script>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <script src={% static "assets/js/owl-carousel.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/scrollreveal.min.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/waypoints.min.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/imgfix.min.js" %}></script>

    <!-- Global Init -->
    <script src={% static  "assets/js/custom.js" %} ></script>


<!-- Prevent this page from coming back  on clicking backbutton-->
{% comment %} <script type="text/javascript" >
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script> {% endcomment %}


  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the **view** for this page to your question.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header that you have set is utter garbage - I would suggest that is the root cause of this displaying incorrectly as the browser has no idea what type of content it is ( in the screenshot )

Comment: Provide the code for your django views. And please remove the repeated text

Answer (score 0):

Try using this at the top of your html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```